# uncaught referenceerror railsadmin is not defined turbo links issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, turbolinks

The railsadmin is mounted at /management. When i visit this page directly i.e http://www.example.com/management then no error is thrown in javascript console.

When i navigate links and then click on a link to railsadmin then this error is thrown. I am pretty sure this is caused by turbolinks. My guess is that since turbo links doesnt load the page fully but only loads part of it, this is the cause of this railsadmin not defined error. How can this be solved? i.e how to prevent this error even when navigating to railsadmin instead of directly visiting railsadmin. I appreciate any help or insights. Thanks

[image]

Comment: This seem like an assets pipeline issue. I would check any settings changed on the assets.rb that might make rails admin not compile the assets. Maybe you are using webpack?

Comment: i am pretty sure this is a turbo links issue because the error only occurs when i navigate to the rails admin page. when i directly visit the railsadmin page then this error doesnt occur.

Comment: What are you doing differently that triggers the error? be more specific please i don't understand your previous message.